# After selected some row from table in XML + XSLT - export to pdf

Tags: xml, xslt, pdf, xsl-fo

Ok. Here is my situation. I've got XML file with data and XSLT with format data. I know that i need propably XSL-FO to convert to PDF format. But i need after select one row with the data about person to convert them in to pdf propably through XSL-FO.

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-2" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="pacienti.xsl"?>
<pacienti>
    <pacient>
        <id>1</id>
        <meno>Jozef</meno>
        <priezvisko>Hubáč</priezvisko>
        <pohlavie>M</pohlavie>
        <DN-den>1</DN-den>
        <DN-mesiac>1</DN-mesiac>
        <DN-rok>1991</DN-rok>
        <pocetRokov>20</pocetRokov>
        <adresa>Lipová 20, Banská Bystrica</adresa>
        <statnaPrislusnost>SK</statnaPrislusnost>
        <rodneCislo>910101/1234</rodneCislo>
        <zdravotnaPoistovna>25</zdravotnaPoistovna>
        <diagnoza>E120</diagnoza>
    </pacient>
    <pacient>
        <id>2</id>
        <meno>Peter</meno>
        <priezvisko>Imrią</priezvisko>
        <pohlavie>M</pohlavie>
        <DN-den>5</DN-den>
        <DN-mesiac>2</DN-mesiac>
        <DN-rok>1990</DN-rok>
        <pocetRokov>21</pocetRokov>
        <adresa>Pietrová 333, Banská ©tiavnica</adresa>
        <statnaPrislusnost>SK</statnaPrislusnost>
        <rodneCislo>900205/5658</rodneCislo>
        <zdravotnaPoistovna>21</zdravotnaPoistovna>
        <diagnoza>A23</diagnoza>
    </pacient> 
</pacienti>
```

and here is XSLT code

```
<body onload="javascript:document.getElementById('vsetko').style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById('podlaPoctuRokovOdNajmensieho').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('podlaPoctuRokovOdNajvecsieho').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('podlaPohlavia').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('podlaStatnejPrislusnosti').style.display = 'none';">

                <div id="vsetko" style="position:relative; top:70px;">
                    <h2>Databáza pacientov (zoradená podµa ID)</h2>
                    <table border="2" id="zvyraznene"  width="100%">
                        <tr  class="tabulcicka" >
                            <th  bgcolor="yellow">Id:</th>
                            <th>Priezvisko, meno:</th>
                            <th>Dátum narodenia:</th>
                            <th>Pohlavie</th>
                            <th>©tátna prísluąnos»</th>
                            <th>Adresa</th>
                            <th>Rodné číslo</th>
                            <th>Zdravotná pois»ovňa</th>
                            <th>Diagnóza</th>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="pacienti/pacient">
                            <xsl:sort select="id" data-type="number">
                            </xsl:sort>
                            <tr  onmouseover="this.className='zvyraznene'" onmouseout="this.className='normalne'">
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="id">
                                    </xsl:value-of>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="priezvisko">
                                    </xsl:value-of>,<xsl:value-of select="meno">
                                    </xsl:value-of>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="DN-den">
                                    </xsl:value-of>.<xsl:value-of select="DN-mesiac">
                                    </xsl:value-of>.<xsl:value-of select="DN-rok">
                                    </xsl:value-of>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="pohlavie">
                                    </xsl:value-of>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="statnaPrislusnost">
                                    </xsl:value-of>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="adresa">
                                    </xsl:value-of>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="rodneCislo">
                                    </xsl:value-of>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="zdravotnaPoistovna">
                                    </xsl:value-of>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center" >
                                    <xsl:value-of select="diagnoza">
                                    </xsl:value-of>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </table>
                </div>


<div id="menu">
                    <input type="button" class="tlacitko" value="Vąetci pacienti" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('vsetko').style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById('podlaPoctuRokovOdNajmensieho').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('podlaPoctuRokovOdNajvecsieho').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('podlaPohlavia').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('podlaStatnejPrislusnosti').style.display = 'none';">
                    </input>
                    <input type="button" class="tlacitko" value="Zoraď podµa pohlavia" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('vsetko').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('podlaPoctuRokovOdNajmensieho').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('podlaPoctuRokovOdNajvecsieho').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('podlaPohlavia').style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById('podlaStatnejPrislusnosti').style.display = 'none';">
                    </input>
                    <input type="button" class="tlacitko" value="Zoraď podµa počtu rokov hore" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('vsetko').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('podlaPoctuRokovOdNajmensieho').style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById('podlaPoctuRokovOdNajvecsieho').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('podlaPohlavia').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('podlaStatnejPrislusnosti').style.display = 'none';">
                    </input>
                    <input type="button" class="tlacitko" value="Zoraď podµa počtu rokov dole" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('vsetko').style.display = 'none';document.getElementById('podlaPoctuRokovOdNajmensieho').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('podlaPoctuRokovOdNajvecsieho').style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById('podlaPohlavia').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('podlaStatnejPrislusnosti').style.display = 'none';">
                    </input>
                    <input type="button" class="tlacitko" value="Zoraď podµa ątátnej prísluąnosti" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('vsetko').style.display = 'none';document.getElementById('podlaPoctuRokovOdNajmensieho').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('podlaPoctuRokovOdNajvecsieho').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('podlaPohlavia').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('podlaStatnejPrislusnosti').style.display = 'block';">
                    </input>
                    <input type="button" class="tlacitko" value="Vytlači»" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='filmyVsetky.pdf';">
                    </input>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

From this source code I am trim the useless data for you. I just need the way to do that. Remember: After select one row with data export to PDF, no all table export to PDF.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The result of XSLT is to create a resultTree (or a set of resultNodes). There is no magic to submit this to XSL-FO. If the result of XSLT is a set of disjoint nodes, then make sure there is a root node containing them as a resultTree (document).

I then suggest two strategies:

- output the resultTree as an XML document and serialize it to file (rows.xml). Then use this as the input to XSL-FO. This may be the easiest if you are using a third party toolset
- route the outputTree directly into the input of XSL-FO. This will be language and package dependent. For example I use Java and would use FOP as the second process. I haven't looked at FOP recently but I am sure it will be able to read an InputStream.